# How to automate definition of .htaccess redirects based on content

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, xargs

I am using

```
grep -HEri "Title\:(content)" ./www.livesite.com/ > Livesite.txt
```

and

```
grep -HEri "Title\:(content)" ./www.devsite.com/ > Devsite.txt
```

to find pairs of paths which have matching or similar content I can specify by regex. When the content from `^/example_found_live_path.html` matches that in `^/different/found_devsite_path`, I want to add a line to the dev site's .htaccess file, creating a 301 redirect from the live site's path to the path found on the dev site, that looks like this:

```
redirect 301 ^/example_live_path.html ^/different/devsite_path
```

The desired result is that on launch, all search engine entries and links to pages from the current live site redirect to pages with matching titles in the dev site.
I feel like this is a job for sed, grep, and xargs but don't know how to structure the command.
Is it like:

```
grep -HEri "Title\:(content)" ./www.livesite.com/ | xargs 'echo %1; grep -HEri %2 ./www.devsite.com' | xargs 'sed "$a\nredirect 301 \^%1 \^%2\n' .htaccess
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide sample input and desired output please?

Comment: The inputs are: all files on the live site, and a unique content identifier. The idea is to identify a piece of content, such as "Title:($the_page_title)" which is unique to the page. The script would then match the content found in the old site to that from the new dev site, returning the URL redirects required for migration in .htaccess format. Output is a file with 1 apache directive per line in 301 redirect syntax.

Comment: when I said "sample" I meant "cut a piece of your file and put it here, as it is" then type what you expect to be the result. from your question I can't even understand what you're trying to do, there's no connection between the greps and the output so far (because you're not showing what the input looks like so I don't know what to extract).

Comment: if I were to guess I'd say that you believe the filesystem path to be equivalent to the url path but that's not always the case, depends on your setup. if you're explicitly mirroring the paths then I suppose it's the path itself what connects the greps with the output and not part of the file, is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: by example, if you had a file `./www.livesite.com/foo/bar.html` with the literal string "Title\:(dashboard)" and also a file `./www.devsite.com/bar_dev.html` with the same string then the output would be `redirect 301 ^/foo/bar.html ^/bar_dev.html` is that it?

Comment: That's it exactly, but the inputs are URLs - and I should have said URL's. Many of the dev URLs that will be requested are already being mod_rewritten by wordpress, so it could be that "Title\:(dashboard)" appears in <./www.livesite.com/foo/bar.html> and <./www.devsite.com/bar_dev>, which would output <redirect 301 ^/foo/bar_dev ^/bar_dev.html>. AFAIK, I have to wget the whole dynamic hierarchy of the dev site, and run this script to compare that folder with a duplicate of the live site root folder. Sorry to be so oblique I really apreciate the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already had the two file lists by running:

```
grep -HEri "Title\:(content)" ./www.livesite.com/ > Livesite.txt
grep -HEri "Title\:(content)" ./www.devsite.com/ > Devsite.txt
```

and got: (there maybe multiple matchings for each found file)

```
(Livesite.txt)
./www.livesite.com/foo/bar1.xhtml:...Title:(content1)........1a
./www.livesite.com/foo/bar1.xhtml:......Title:(content3)........1b
./www.livesite.com/goo/car.xhtml:....Title:(content4)........1c
...

(Devsite.txt)
./www.devsite.com/bar_dev.html:......Title:(content2)...2a
./www.devsite.com/far_zoo.html:...Title:(content4).........2b
./www.devsite.com/far_zoo.html:...Title:(content3).........2c
...
```

The join result should be:

```
1a - null
1b - 2c
1c - 2b
null - 2a
```

Here is the script to inner-join the two lists on the matching content:

```
while IFS=: read livepath line1; do
    matching1="${line1#*Title:(}"
    matching1="${matching1%)*}"

    matched=0
    matched_devpath=
    while IFS=: read devpath line2; do
        matching2="${line2#*Title:(}"
        matching2="${matching2%)*}"
        if [ "$matching1" = "$matching2" ]; then
            matched=1
            matched_devpath="$devpath"
            break
        fi
    done <Devsite.txt

    if [ "$matched" = 1 ]; then
        url1="${livepath#./www.livesite.com}"
        url2="${devpath#./www.devsite.com}"
        echo "301 ^$url1 ^$url2"
    fi
done <Livesite.txt
```

and the result should be:

```
redirect 301 ^/foo/bar1.html ^/far_zoo.html
redirect 301 ^/goo/car.html ^/far_zoo.html
```

Umm.. good luck!